# Failed to run react native project on IOS Simulator

Tags: ios, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/st8s6.png)I'm new to react native, I'm following the official React native's website to init a new project, try to run IOS. But, failed with the error below.
React-Native version 0.59
XCode 10.2

> error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it
>   exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider
>   building your app with Xcode.app, by opening HelloWorld.xcodeproj

When I run react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 7" 
Error as below:

```
info Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

info 

error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening HelloWorld.xcodeproj
```

Comment: Could it be the react-native & XCode version mismatched?

Comment: Go to react project folder inside that folder you will find ios, open that inside that double click on .xcodeproj, clean and build(HelloWorldProject-> ios -> .xcodeProj)

Comment: @channu- Thanks for prompt response. I will give a try

Comment: @channu - It doesn't work for me. I'm having the same error, please see the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Starting the simulator : Once you have your React Native project initialized, you can run react-native run-ios inside the newly created project directory. If everything is set up correctly, you should see your new app running in the iOS Simulator shortly.
Specifying a device : You can specify the device the simulator should run with the `--simulator` flag, followed by the device name as a string. The default is `"iPhone X"`. If you wish to run your app on an iPhone 4s, just run `react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 4s"`.

The device names correspond to the list of devices available in Xcode. You can check your available devices by running `xcrun simctl`list devices from the console.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was specifying a simulator, but I had a different simulator open. Targeting the one that was opened, or simply closing it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this and see if it works or not.

first go to to ios folder of the project in terminal.

for that you can use terminal in visual studio code.

`cd ios` then

`pod install`

go back (to app directory)
`cd ..`

`npm install`

`npm start`

take a new terminal then,
`npx react-native run-ios`